# PHP: Unserialize Data That Has Been Serialized & Inserted Into A Mysql Database & Echo To A Table In PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I have managed to serialize data (an Array) and insert it into a column in a database. I'd like to now SELECT that column and turn it back into and array and list each element of the array on a separate row.

> what i am struggling with:

struggling with the array that i have unserialized. The reason i am Serializing in the first place is i am working with a multi-dimensional array that can have 1 or many items in an order.

once i have INSERTED the serialized data into the Mysql Database, the information looks like the following:

> Example 1 - [One item in the order with a Quantity of 1].

```
 a:1:{i:7354028228659;a:1:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;}}
```

I'd like to unserialize it and populate it in a PHP table with the structure below.

```
|   Varaint_id  | Quantity | 
|---------------|----------|
| 7354028228659 |    1     |         
|---------------|----------|
```

If there is more than one item in the order, i'd like to achieve the same layout.

> Example 2 - [3 items in the order each with a Quantity of 1].

```
a:3:{i:6836781613107;a:1:{s:8:"quantity";i:2;}i:6737290241;a:1:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;}i:49366524679;a:1:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;}}
```

The following below is a representation on the above, three items in the order each having 1 unit on order.

```
----------------------------
|   Varaint_id  | Quantity | 
----------------|-----------
| 6836781613107 |    1     |         
|---------------|----------|
| 6737290241    |    1     |         
|---------------|----------|
| 49366524679   |    1     |         
|---------------|----------|
```

What i'm currently struggling with is turning the string back into an array and then displaying it in a table using php.

> Current Methodology:
>
> Step 1 - 
>   Run SELECT query to the Database:
>   Step 2 - 
>   Fetch $stmt & Unserialize column 'items' from database. NOTE: I am struggling here!
>   Step 3 - 
>   Echo results into a table.

```
//1. Running a SELECT query to the Database.
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT items, order_number, cust_fname
                    From orders
                    WHERE '".$order_number."' = order_number");

//2. Fetch $stmt & Unserialize column 'items' from database.
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    $results = unserialize($row['items']);

//3. Echo results into a table. 
    echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $results . "</td>
        <td>" . $results . "</td> 
        </tr>";
 };
```

I'm not sure how to loop through the array and Unserialize the data and then echo just the variant_id in the one column and the quantity in the other column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its an array, you said that at least twice. So process it like any other array

Comment: Start by showing yourself the array! Do a `<pre>print_r($results,1);</pre>`

Comment: A little bit off topic; but have you considered [normalizing your database?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) . If you're not forced into this route of storing an array, pulling the array, unserializing the array, searching the array... Then it may be a more efficient route.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thanks for the prompt response! I  get that it's an array. I'm having difficulty processing it in the format i'd like to achieve as this is the first time i have worked with serialization. when i do a print_r($results) i get the following:

Array ( [7354028228659] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) )

Comment: Then the first thing you should have tried is a foreach l;oop

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks! will do that. Cheers

Comment: "The reason i am Serializing in the first place is"....wrong. Normalize your data.

Comment: @symcbean, I will work towards this. cheers

Comment: The fact you are using an array in your PHP code is not a reason for using blobs in your database. PHP doesn't do "multi-dimensional array"s they are nested arrays, and what you have shown here is that the data has an invariant hierarchy (even more reason not to serialize).

Answer (score 1):

as mensionned by @RiggsFolly , you can consume your array like any other array.

```
//1. Running a SELECT query to the Database.
// This other approch to query is not sensitive to SQL injection.
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT items, order_number, cust_fname
    From orders
    WHERE order_number = :order_number
 ");

 $stmt->execute([
    ':order_number' => $order_number
 ]);

//2. Fetch $stmt & Unserialize column 'items' from database.
 while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $results = unserialize($row['items']);
    //3. Echo results into a table. 
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($results as $varaint_id => $result) {
        echo '<td>'.$result['quantity'].</td>
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I know is not the actual topic, but let me point dangerous SQL injection issue on your code.

your code :

```
$db->query("SELECT items, order_number, cust_fname
    From orders
    WHERE '".$order_number."' = order_number
     ");
```

is sensitive to attack who can looks like :

```
$order_number = "1' --";
$myQuery = "SELECT items, order_number, cust_fname
        From orders
        WHERE '".$order_number."' = order_number
         "

// Will result 
SELECT items, order_number, cust_fname
        From orders
        WHERE '1'--' = order_number'
```

notice `--` is one way to comment rest of the line in MySQL, this query will output all row inside orders.

By `PDO::prepare` and `PDO::execute` you avoid this kind of attack.

[More information](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: thank you so much for raising that issue! I will amend that immediately.

Comment: haha my bad @IsThisJavascript i change this miss typo - @Simonious is this fix your original issue ? If no, please send us your `var_dump` output

Comment: just getting this at the moment with when running a foreach:

array(1) { ["quantity"]=> int(1) } array(1) { ["quantity"]=> int(1) }